# PHP "if" condition error

Tags: php, if-statement, random

Error in `if` condition. I am trying to generate 5digit random no, and verify that random no and textbox values `($_POST['otp1'])` equal move to `thank.php` page else show popup error.

I did everything, if textbox values and `$otp` value is equal it showing popup message.

Following is the code

otp.php

```
<form action="otp.php" method="post">
<label>Mobile :</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" /> <br /><br />
<label>OTP :</label>
<input type="text" name="otp1" /> <br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Verifiy" />
</form>

<?php

$otp = intval( "0" . rand(1,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) );
echo $otp;

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{

    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $otp_no = $_POST['otp1'];

    if($otp_no != $otp) \\ Condition not work
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Your OTP is Worng'); window.location.replace(\"otp.php\");</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: thank.php');

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you know that if the page refreshes/get redirect with form the number get generated again?

Comment: you cant send headers in php once you have outputted html.  You _should_ get an error.   Are you saying that the false side of the `if` works but the true side doesnt?  Have you done anything to debug the values of `$otp_no` and `$otp`?

Comment: so what i want to do now ? can i remove the redirect

Comment: see the answer from @b0s3 for a solution, but to stop the header issue move the php to the top, before the html.

Comment: No that one also same problem. 
 
please see this [My website](http://justdailme.info/otp/otp.php) @ DevDonkey

Comment: thank you for helping me guyz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the otp code is changed in form submit. so you have to store otp code in hidden element and compare it with user's entered otp value.

```
<?php
$otp = intval( "0" . rand(1,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) );
echo $otp;
?>
<form action="test1.php" method="post">
<label>Mobile :</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" /> <br /><br />
<label>OTP :</label>
<input type="hidden" name="otp" value="<?=$otp?>" /> 
<input type="text" name="otp1"  /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Verifiy" />
</form>

<?php

//$otp = intval( "0" . rand(1,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) );
//echo $otp;

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
  $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
  $otp_no = $_POST['otp1'];
  $otp = $_POST['otp'];

  if($otp_no != $otp) // Condition not work
  {
      echo "<script>alert('Your OTP is Worng'); </script>";
  }
  else
  {
      echo "success";

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you explain me why you add hidden type

Answer (score 2):

When the page reloads the `$otp` is regenerated. So it will never match. Try with -

```
sesstion_start();

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{

    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $otp_no = $_POST['otp1'];

    if($otp_no !== $_SESSION['otp']) \\ Check identical
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Your OTP is Worng');window.location.replace(\"otp.php\");</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        unset($_SESSION['otp']); // Unset the otp in session
        header('Location: thank.php');

    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['otp'] = intval( "0" . rand(1,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) );
    echo $_SESSION['otp'];
}
```

Comment: No this one also same problem @ b0s3

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($otp_no)` & `var_dump($_SESSION['otp'])` before the check and exit?